# How to don't calculate datediff if I have the line following itself the same

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, datediff

I have issue in R in dplyr. I calculate diffdate bettween dates and I create new column, but I want to omit when status a line following itself (row +1) is the same. It should be NA or 0.

```
serial      status             date       days days2
312313124   Good Stock         20/01/2021 0    0
312313124   Under Assessment   29/01/2021 9    9
312313124   In Repair          03/02/2021 4    4
312313124   Under Assessment   06/02/2021 3    3 <- is correct, because between status: Under is other status
70453423040 Under Assessment   18/03/2021 0    0
70453423040 In Repair          25/03/2021 7    0
70453423040 In Repair          28/03/2021 3    0 <- should be NA or 0, because in the same serial, status before (1 line above) is the same
12131231    Good Stock         03/04/2021 6
```

I try regroup by my data, but doesn't work. I use this code.:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(Serial) %>%
  mutate(Days = c(NA, as.numeric(diff(Exported), units='days'))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Serial, Status, Date) %>%
  mutate(Days2 = if_else(row_number() > 1 , NA, Days)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I try also, but this code shows me when I have duplicate, even when diff between record is more than 2.

```
df3<- df%>%
  group_by(Serial, Status) %>%
  mutate(Days2 = +duplicated((paste(Serial, Status)))
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace `group_by(Serial, Status, Date)` by `group_by(Serial, Status)`?

Comment: I tried. Sometimes I have the same date. If I use duplicate they find all duplicate records, not only in the adjacent rows, but whole group by. E.x. xxx yyy xxx and this combination is ok, but this xxx xxx yyy nope. I need something like a duplicated in pairs. If second rows from pair has the same serial and status give me 0 like in my example above with status 'in repair'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `lag` / `lead`. Something like the following:

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(Serial) %>%
  mutate(next_date = lead(date, 1, order_by = date),
         next_status = lead(status, 1, order_by = date)) %>%
  mutate(Days2 = ifelse(status != next_status, next_date - date, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's works. Earlier I didn't know this function lead. Really helpful! :)